# Billing fields does not add required

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a code below, it adds the field with label but does not add required field not sure why.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 
'override_default_address_fields');
function override_default_address_fields($address_fields)
{
$address_fields['billing']['billing_address_2'] = array(
    'label'     => __('Mobile', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => true,

);


return $address_fields;
}
```

Any help is appreciated! thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not familiar wiht wordpress, but shouldn't the value of required be `required` ? I don't know how te array is handled by the HTML generator in your case, but the correct and standard html5 syntax is `required="required"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're doing it wrong...

instead of `['billing_address_2']`, use your own like `['billing_mobile']`.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'override_default_address_fields');
function override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['billing']['billing_mobile'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Mobile', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => true,
    );
    return $address_fields;
}
```

with what you are doing you're overriding `['billing_address_2']`. Which I think you are seeing it as a problem because you are only seeing the `Mobile` label.